# Problemas con emojis en Python

Tags: python, print

Buenas tardes actualmente estoy teniendo problemas con agregar emojis de cualqueir tipo de medio en Python 3, estoy usando visual code studio, tengo instalado el modulo de emoji, probe por unicode y no entiendo por que me salen signos de pregunta y ahora volviendo a probar para asegurarme que no hacia nada mal me di cuenta que al ejecutar el programa muchas veces a veces sale el emoji y a veces no, adjunto foto

el codigo es sensillo de por si, debe ser un problema que me falta instalar algo en la computadora o debo tener algun directorio mal pero no tengo idea que puede ser por eso pido ayuda

[image: foto]

```
icono_attack = ('\U0001FA93')
print(icono_attack)
```

Comment: *debe ser un problema que me falta instalar algo en la computadora o debo tener algun directorio mal pero no tengo idea que puede ser por eso pido ayuda*... y si nos dejas ver el código para que podamos juzgarlo nosotros mismos? Porque si no será muy difícil saber cual es realmente el error que puedas tener. Podría inventarme una solución muy sencilla de por si, pero a lo mejor te interesa más una respuesta que te solucione el problema correctamente, cierto? :) Te recomiendo leer [ask] y hacer el [tour] para que entiendas mejor cómo funcionamos y tus preguntas sean mejor aceptadas

Comment: esta escribo ahi abajo es solo esa linea, una variable que almacena el emoji y printearlo

Comment: Y la etiqueta del lenguaje que usas?? `print` es un método que existe en casi todos los lenguajes de programación. Asumo que usas python?

Comment: si lo escribi en el titulo, como tambien al principio del texto

Comment: Ah si disculpa. Normalmente no me paro a leer cada palabra de lo que escribe la gente, para eso filtramos por etiquetas ^^'. Te recomiendo que empieces por eliminar los paréntesis de `icono_attack = ('\U0001FA93')`. De todas las maneras, es muy posible que el error esté causado por la consola en la que estás imprimiendo, en qué consola estás ejecutando el código?

Comment: probe sacar los parentesis y sigue igual, estoy usando el IDE de Visual Studio Code, en todo caso tambien me siguen saliendo signos de pregunta aun si lo ejecuto desde la terminal de python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tiene más pinta de ser un *bug* de la consola de VSCode. Para que una consola pueda mostrar un emoji, no sólo debe ser capaz de decodificar el código Unicode, sino además de tener la fuente necesaria que contenga ese emoji. Una consola estándar de Windows por ejemplo no sería capaz de mostrarlo.

La consola incrustada en VScode, aunque emula una terminal como la que aparecería con CMD, sí que tiene soporte Unicode, y por tanto debería ser capaz de mostrar el emoji. No obstante parece que algunos problemas sí que hay. Yo intenté ejecutar tu código y no obtuve el emoji, sino los símbolos de carácter no válido que te aparecen a ti. Sin embargo, intenté repetir el experimento para pegar aquí una captura de pantalla y ahora el emoji ya me sale bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si en vez de usar CMD como shell utilizo Git Bash (también integrado en VSCode) la cosa va bastante peor:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Modifiqué el programa para que imprimiera seis veces el emoji y como ves a veces sale las seis mal, otras veces saca mal aleatoriamente parte de los caracteres... Definitivamente es un bug de VSCode.

Lamento no poder date una solución, pero al menos te he confirmado que el problema no es culpa tuya. Tiene toda la pinta de tratarse de [esta issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/92409).